# Any synonyms for "requiredness"?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

I need to reduce "Is it required?" to a single word for an input label in a web form and also for a column name in the database. Any suggestions what to name the field?

> Enter field name `|____________|`
>
> Requiredness <radio-field>
>   `O YES`
>   `O No`
>   `O Recommended`

.

> ```
> +--------------+--------------+--------------+
>                |              |Requiredness  |
> +--------------+--------------+--------------+
>                |              |yes           |
>                |              |no            |
>                |              |recommended   |
> ```

Is Requiredness a right word here? Any more suggestions?

Comment: Good question. I can only think of other made-up words like *mandatoricity.*

Comment: I build form engines often. I've always just used one word, with a question mark: **"Required?"** It implies a question, no need for extra words.

Comment: @lux but here we can't use a question mark, said the OP.

Comment: @NVZ Okay, remove the question mark? It's the desired nomenclature to boot: http://www.leemunroe.com/required-fields/ (*required field*)

Comment: @lux now that makes sense. :)

Comment: Thanks @lux. Though `required` also looks okay but the question mark troubles me. I was looking for a noun actually. I don't deny that `required` is used by almost everyone in this context but I felt that a noun would fit perfectly as a table column name.

Comment: Good point, ok last one :-) Dependent/dependency.

Comment: What did you find in a thesaurus?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider [**necessity**](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/necessity), from ODO

> The state or fact of being required
>
> *the necessity of providing parental guidance:*

It is a synonym of [requiredness](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/requiredness), from ODO

> The fact or quality of being required; necessity, obligatoriness

I'm no programmer, but **requiredness** is okay to be used for this purpose. Here's [an example from IBM site](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21120039).

Or simply using **required** would be fine.

Comment: Thanks for that link. It gives me a little confidence to zero in on requiredness. Yet I also realize that required would rather be better.

Answer (score 3):

You could use **need**. After all, require means to need something.

Here is a fancy word, **desideration**, from [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/desideration)

> The act of desiderating. (expressing a need or wish to have or attain)
>
> Something desired or required.

Also, Try [demand](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/demand)  - a strong need for something.

Comment: Requiredness connotes gradientness to me. I'm a rare user of field entry forms and requiredness would throw me. Even without the question mark, the response options imply it well enough: